# Determining of option is initial value in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm manually rendering a modelchoicefield in my form so that I can insert a custom attribute on each option. I'd like to know what template tag I can userto determine if the option is the initial value so that I can set it as the selected option in the dropdown menu on page load.

**forms.py**

```
    self.fields['formpricing'].choices = ZERO_BLANK_CHOICE + tuple([(t.id, t) for t in FormPricingMethod.objects.filter(industryname=industry)])
    self.fields['formpricing'].queryset = FormPricingMethod.objects.filter(industryname=industry)
```

**views.py**

```
formpricing = userprofile.formpricing 
form3 = BasisOfPricingForm(request.POST or None, user=user, initial={'formpricing': formpricing})
```

**template**

```
<div class="fieldname">Form Pricing</div>
   <div class="fieldvalue">
      <select name="formpricing" required="" id="id_formpricing">

           {% for value, object in form3.formpricing.field.choices %}

               <option typenumber="{{object.typenumber}}" value="{{value}}">
                   {{object.title}}
               </option>

           {% endfor %}    

     </select>
   </div>                       
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

{% if form3.formpricing.initial.id == value %}selected{% endif %}